# Cookies getting lost

Tags: asp.net, iis, cookies

I am transferring data from one aspx web page to another using cookies. It is working perfectly in the local (local host) machine IIS 7.5 but not on IIS 8.0 server after publishing

```
Response.Cookies["UserBID"].Value = "11111";
        Response.Cookies["AppID"].Value = "161";
        Response.Cookies["RoleID"].Value = "6";
        Response.Cookies["ActiveOnly"].Value = "1";
        Response.Cookies["UserBID"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        Response.Cookies["AppID"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        Response.Cookies["RoleID"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        Response.Cookies["ActiveOnly"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        //Response.Redirect("http://localhost:49752/Usermgmt.aspx");
        Response.Redirect("http://dnadev/GlobalUserManagement/Usermgmt.aspx",false);
```

getting back

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserBID"] != null)
        {
            UserBID = Request.Cookies["UserBID"].Value.ToString();
        }
        if (Request.Cookies["AppID"] != null)
        {
            AppID = Request.Cookies["AppID"].Value.ToString();
        }
        if (Request.Cookies["RoleID"] != null)
        {
            RoleID = Request.Cookies["RoleID"].Value.ToString();
        }
        if (Request.Cookies["ActiveOnly"] != null)
        {
            ActiveOnly = Request.Cookies["ActiveOnly"].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

From what code you've given I cant really tell what the problem is. I will attempt to answer your question by walking through the process. When you set a cookie in the response you should use `Response.SetCookie(MyCookie);` This will not make duplicate cookies. When just setting the value of cookies it can potentially create duplicates. After you set the cookie you will have to reload the page or visit another one for the cookie to be set. It will not show up in the `Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];` Other than that I don't see any problems with your code.

Set Cookie:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserBid", "11197");
HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

Get Cookie Value:

```
var bid = (Request.Cookies["UserBid"] != null) ? Request.Cookies["UserBid"].Value : "";
```

Comment: I have tried you code and still not able to get the value once I publish the code in the IIS 8 server.